# Using Vue.js + Jekyll multilingual

Tags: vue.js, internationalization, jekyll, liquid

I am using [Jekyll](https://jekyllrb.com/) with
[jekyll-multiple-languages-plugin](https://github.com/kurtsson/jekyll-multiple-languages-plugin)  and I want to use **Vue.js + Webpack** as well.
I cannot understand the proper way to do this.

Jekyll uses .yml files to store data, and then Liquid tags like this {% translate title %} to provide data per language.

I **can** set src folder and all the vue scaffolding in _site folder ,
run `bundle exec jekyll serve`
and then run `npm run serve` from _site and use translations in the vue like this:

```
---
layout: default
---
<template>
  <h1>{% translate title %}</h1>
</template>
```

But this is of course will leave me with just cloned compiled vue apps per language.

How can I properly pass variables from my i18n/en.yml and i18n/de.yml translations into Vue.js and compile it with Webpack?

Answer (score 0):

The data folder from Jekyll is `_data`, see [Jekyll-docs](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/datafiles/).

The content of the _data folder will not be "moved" to the output `_site` but can be used during building your site.

Comment: Thank for the answer, but I am still having trouble understanfing my steps.
if i have my en.yml in data folder and I am trying to call it via
`<template>
  <h1>{% for lang in site.data.en %}{{  site.data.lang.title }}{% endfor %}</h1>
</template>`
I still get a  Cannot read property 'data' of undefined in chrome upon build

Comment: I, of course have the title: "Hello world" in the en.yml
It seems that the vue.js trying to access site.data.lang.title as a js variable?

Comment: can you share your en.yml? Here or as gist in github?

Comment: Have you done, these steps from the docu? https://github.com/kurtsson/jekyll-multiple-languages-plugin#41-_configyml

Comment: Hello @KargWare, my en.yml is literally one line, for the sake of testing:
`title: "Hello EARTHLING!"` and thats it, nothing more is there.
I am using jekyll-multiple-languages-plugin for a long time and built many sites with it, the plugin itself is not causing any issue. I am not understanding how the two build processes (the jekyll build and the vue build) can co-exist within one timeframe. The only solution I see is to first run Jekyll and then build Vue, but I think there is a more adequate way to achieve this.